# Use the Cauchy Integral Formula to evaluate the following integrals:

Tags: complex-analysis

We are being tested next week on the Cauchy Integral Formula, and were given these questions as guidelines.

1) $\int_\gamma \frac{\cos(z)dz}{z(z^2+1)}$ where $\gamma$ is the circle with center $0$ and radius $3$

2) $\int_\gamma \frac{e^z dz}{z^2+1}$ where $\gamma$ is the circle centered at $i$ with radius $1$

3) $\int_\gamma \frac{zdz}{z^2+4}$ where $\gamma$ is the rectangle with vertices $1 \pm 4i$

4) $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^3+1}$ where $\gamma$ is the circle with center $-1$ and radius $\frac{7}{4}$

5) $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^3+1}$ where $\gamma$ is the circle with center $0$ and radius $4$

I solved question 2 by doing the following:

Solved for the poles; $z = \pm i$

Only the pole at i is inside $\gamma$, so write the function as $\frac{\frac{e^z}{z+i}}{z-i}$, which is equal to $2\pi i \cdot \frac{e^i}{2i}$, which gives $\pi(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))$

With regards to question 3, $\gamma$ confused me, as I had a hard time telling what poles were inside it.

With the other questions, I was unsure of how to re-write the function in terms of poles when there were more than 2 poles.

For example, for question 1, I found the poles to be $z = 0$, $z = \pm i$ This could be re-written as $\frac{\frac{\frac{cos(z)}{z}}{z-i}}{z+i}$, but I am unsure of how to proceed. Should I let $z = -i$ and sub that into $\frac{\frac{\cos(z)}{z}}{z-i}$?

I was having the same issue with 4 and 5 where I didn't know how to proceed when the function was re-written with 3 poles.

Comment: You can use partial fraction decomposition, for example, $\dfrac{\cos(z)}{z(z^2+1)}=\cos(z) \bigg(\dfrac{1}{z}-\dfrac{1}{2(z-i)}-\dfrac{1}{2(z+i)}\bigg)$ and then integrate that.

Comment: just use partial fraction decomposition